# MobileServiceClient Error

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Currently, I developed Xamarin.Forms Application and integrate with Azure Mobile Services.
[image]

And my Constants as below:
[image]

**and it display this Error:**

Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not found.
[image]

Any solutions for this?

Comment: What other global setup do you have for System.Net.Http.HttpClient?  There must be something there, as this does not happen for a new Xamarin Forms project.

Comment: @AdrianHall The current happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

It's caused by the latest update version of library.

You can find the solutions here info here

http://motzcod.es/post/150988588867/updating-azure-mobile-sqlitestore-to-30

I solved it by downgrade the library

Comment: This shouldn't be happening as of v3.0.2 of the library as all the issues with 3.0.0 were fixed in that release.  Hate to say it, but something else is going on here.